# Same table doing multiple operation in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-insert

Table `emp` with columns:

```
 id | name | sal | deptno | location
```

One user is inserting/updating 20 million records into that table.

Another user is retrieving data using select statement from the same `emp` table.

insert / update statement will take 2 hours and at the same time another user retrieve data in the mid of insertion/update process

How many records will come  for execute the select statement in SQL?

How to check or what steps we need to follow to achieve this task in SQL Server?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking here.  Please show some data which might help to explain your question.

Comment: What transaction isolation level?  I READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT database option set?  Is the SELECT trying to read every row and column?  What is the complete table DDL including indexes?  Why does the INSERT take 2 hours?

Comment: Based on your transaction isolation level this can have different behaviours. But from your point I think the answer that would satisfy you provided long-lasting insert statement is that a select will not pull in the rows which aren't in the table yet.

Comment: You also say it might be update, so that could block the reading process for the 2 hours. You should try it and see what happens, and for example use [sp_whoisactive](http://whoisactive.com/)

Comment: You can use `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM emp` to get how many are inserted.